# How can I fix CSS styles

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to modify my CSS styles to make the design look exactly like the following picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwwhz.png)

At the moment my design looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ISyH.png)

Here my code

```
     <div class="row">
        <h4 class="font-form">Documentos adjuntos</h4>
          <div class="item-container">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listDoc">
                  <div class="item-list">
                    <img src="./assets/img/radicar.svg" alt="" height="40px" />
                    <p class="item-text">{{ item.nombreArchivo }}</p>
                    <a [href]="item.archivoBase64" target="_blank" mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon class="icons">visibility</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                 <div class="item-description">Acta</div>
                </ng-container>
          </div>
      </div>
```

```
.item-container {
  background-color: #f4f5f8;
  border-radius: 12px; 
  }

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0px; 
  }

.item-text {
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 15px;
  }

.item-description {
  background-color: #BC293E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  }
```

The white div I also need to leave it the same as the image. Currently it is taking up the whole width, and I would like them to be positioned side by side, but the red label to stay at the bottom.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOOs.png)

Answer (score 0):

for item container, you can use grid:

```css
.item-container {
  background-color: #f4f5f8;
  border-radius: 12px; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

this will set your container element to have a grid display with 4 items in a row and also 1rem of gap in between of cells.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  column-gap:50px;
  background-color: #f4f5f8;
  padding:10px;
}

.font-form{
  width:100%;
}

.item-container {
  
  border-radius: 12px; 
  display:flex;
}

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0px; 
  }

.item-text {
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 15px;
  }

ng-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.item-description {
  background-color: #BC293E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  }
```

```html
   <h4 class="font-form">Documentos adjuntos</h4>
   <div class="row">
          <div class="item-container">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listDoc">
                  <div class="item-list">
                    <img src="./assets/img/radicar.svg" alt="" height="40px" />
                    <p class="item-text">{{ item.nombreArchivo }}</p>
                    <a [href]="item.archivoBase64" target="_blank" mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon class="icons">visibility</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                 <div class="item-description">Acta</div>
                </ng-container>
          </div>
     
     <div class="item-container">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listDoc">
                  <div class="item-list">
                    <img src="./assets/img/radicar.svg" alt="" height="40px" />
                    <p class="item-text">{{ item.nombreArchivo }}</p>
                    <a [href]="item.archivoBase64" target="_blank" mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
                      <mat-icon class="icons">visibility</mat-icon>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                 <div class="item-description">Acta</div>
                </ng-container>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Is this what you've wanted? (look at the full page view)

Comment: It does not work, the white div must be positioned side by side, and the red label must be placed underneath on the left side of each white div displayed on the screen.

Comment: It is positioned side by side. Do you mean it has to scroll horizontally? I see the red label positioned where you wanted to be.

Answer (score 0):

try this code but add the svgs to it, and more divs(with **item-container** class).

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.font-form {
  color: #6f6f6f;
}

.items-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f4f5f8;
}

.item-container {
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.item-list {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.item-text {
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 15px;
}

.item-description {
  background-color: #bc293e;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <h4 class="font-form">Documentos adjuntos</h4>
      <div class="items-container">
        <div class="item-container">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listDoc">
            <div class="item-list">
              <img src="./assets/img/radicar.svg" alt="" height="40px" />
              <p class="item-text">PDF.pdf</p>
              <a
                [href]="item.archivoBase64"
                target="_blank"
                mat-button
                matSuffix
                mat-icon-button
              >
                <mat-icon class="icons">visibility</mat-icon>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-description">Acta</div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
        <div class="item-container">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listDoc">
            <div class="item-list">
              <img src="./assets/img/radicar.svg" alt="" height="40px" />
              <p class="item-text">PDF.pdf</p>
              <a
                [href]="item.archivoBase64"
                target="_blank"
                mat-button
                matSuffix
                mat-icon-button
              >
                <mat-icon class="icons">visibility</mat-icon>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-description">Acta</div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```